# UIBarButtonItem with rounded corners and shadow

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uibutton

I want to have rounded corners and shadow on a `UIBarButtonItem`.

```
UIButton *useButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
```

Then I try to set shadow and rounded corners:

```
useButton.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
useButton.layer.cornerRadius = 4;
useButton.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1.5);
useButton.layer.shadowRadius = 0.5;
useButton.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0;
useButton.layer.shadowColor = [BSTCMColorUtility colorFromHexString:@"#AFAFAF"].CGColor;
```

Finally I make the `UIBarButtonItem`:

```
UIBarButtonItem *useItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:useButton];
[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItems:@[useItem]];
```

I get no rounded corners, but I do get the shadow.

If I add:

```
useButton.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

And/or:

```
useButton.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

I get rounded corners, but no shadow. So I thought that I would try to add a sublayer.

```
CALayer *useButtonShadowLayer = [CALayer new];
useButtonShadowLayer.frame = useButton.frame;
useButtonShadowLayer.cornerRadius = 4;
useButtonShadowLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
useButtonShadowLayer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1.5);
useButtonShadowLayer.shadowRadius = 0.5;
useButtonShadowLayer.shadowOpacity = 1.0;
useButtonShadowLayer.shadowColor = [BSTCMColorUtility colorFromHexString:@"#AFAFAF"].CGColor;

useButton.layer.cornerRadius = 4;
useButton.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

UIView *parent = useButton.superview;
[parent.layer insertSublayer:useButtonShadowLayer below:useButton.layer];
```

It doesn't seem to work, I see no shadow. I get rounded corners tho.

Isn't possible to have rounded corners AND shadow on a `UIBarButtonItem`/`UIButton`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this Updated code :

```
UIButton *useButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
useButton.frame = CGRectMake(100, 430, 100, 40);
useButton.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
useButton.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
useButton.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1.5, 1.5);
useButton.layer.shadowRadius = 0.5;
useButton.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0;
useButton.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
useButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

UIBarButtonItem *useItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:useButton];
[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItems:@[useItem]];
```

Comment: Custom type. It's in the question, first line of code

Comment: In my first version of the question I forgot to mention that I use the button to make a UIBarButtonItem. Maybe that is the problem...

Comment: It works, but not when I use the button to make a UIBarButtonItem. I forgot to mention that in my first version of the question.

Comment: @Johannes its working on UIBarButtonItem as well i checked it

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure where my error is, I pasted all of your code in to a new project and it works there. So I gotta have an error somewhere else in my project :)

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question. If you set `masksToBounds` to `NO` then the corner radius isn't visible anymore.

Answer (score 4):

```
    UIButton *useButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    useButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 30);
    useButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    useButton.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
    useButton.layer.cornerRadius = 4;
    useButton.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1.5);
    useButton.layer.shadowRadius = 5;
    useButton.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0;
//    useButton.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    useButton.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    [self.view addSubview:useButton];

    UIBarButtonItem *useItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:useButton];
    [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItems:@[useItem]];
```

Comment: Thanks. It must be the fact that I'm actually "wrapping" the UIButton in a UIBarButtonItem to set the right bar button item in my navigation bar.

Answer (score 0):

```
btnname.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0;
btnname.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(2, 2);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
btn.layer.cornerRadius = 2.0 ;
```

Answer (score -5):

```
buttonName.layer.cornerRadius = 2;
buttonName.layer.borderWidth = 1;
buttonName.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blacColor].CGColor;
```