# How to place profile image on uibarbuttonitem with rounded corners in objective c?

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem, uinavigationitem, ios8.3

I want to make my UIbarbuttonItem with rounded corners (the right). [I referred the link to implement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23886528/uibarbuttonitem-with-rounded-corners-and-shadow) still I'm not getting.The image comes from URL.My code is,

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0,0), ^{

 NSData * data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL   URLWithString:userImage]];
    if ( data == nil )
        return;
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // WARNING: is the cell still using the same data by this point??
        UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData: data];

        UIImage *btnImage = [self imageWithImage:img scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(50, 50)];
        UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        // btn.bounds = CGRectMake( 0, 0, btnImage.size.width, btnImage.size.height );
        [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(action:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
        [btn setImage:btnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        UIBarButtonItem *btnItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btn];
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = btnItem;
    });

});
```

[image]
I need to implement the same as the image.What I' doing wrong,please anybody help me to fix this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works for me:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
 {
 [super viewDidLoad];
  NSString* url = @"https://i.stack.imgur.com/EbYBY.jpg";
 NSData * data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL   URLWithString:url]];
UIImage* img = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

UIImageView* v = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40)];
v.image = img;
v.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
v.layer.cornerRadius = 20;

UIBarButtonItem* rightBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:v];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBtn;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Strange. As you can see on screenshot - code is working. Maybe problem is in your NavigationItem... Can you add any other rightButtonItem to it?

Comment: I'm not sure, what i'm doing wrong.I used the same code  on another viewcontroller I faced the same issue.can you pls suggest some solution

Comment: 1. check self.navigationItem , maybe it has wrong size or it is nil. 2. Try to add simple rightItem (only text, without image)

Comment: I try to create navigationbar programmatically with UIbarbuttonItem, it works fine.But I place UInavigationabar with userinterface this code not working

Answer (score 8):

Here's [oxigen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/91674/oxigen)'s (excellent) answer converted to Swift 3 / Swift 4:

```swift
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let url = URL(string: "https://i.stack.imgur.com/EbYBY.jpg")!
    let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url)
    let img = UIImage(data: data)
    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 40.0, height: 40.0))
    imageView.image = img?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
    imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 20.0
    imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
    let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: imageView)
    navigationItem.setLeftBarButton(barButton, animated: false)
}
```

(The given URL is dead now, but with a proper URL, or other image, the code should work.)

Answer (score 0):

You can make the button round by using this

```
UIButton * btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
btn.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,100,100)//set your frame's size
[btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:btnImage]  forState:UIControlStateNormal];  
btn.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
btn.layer.cornerRadius = btn.bounds.size.width/2;;

UIBarButtonItem * btnItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btn];
[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItems:@[btnItem]];
```

Comment: But I'm not getting the image itself

Comment: Are you sure image is coming from the URL?

Comment: Yes,I'm getting image from URL.

Comment: Place it in another imageview or some other button and check, if it is displaying.. So that you can be sure if image is only not showing in UIBarButtonItem

Comment: yes,I did the same.Image displaying in  imageview.Only with UIbarbuttonItem it not working

Comment: Delete the build from your simulator/device. Clean this build and then run and see.. Also check if UIBarButtonItem is showing, without image?

Comment: I'm using two XIB's, Is there any issue with that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82674/discussion-between-munahil-and-iniyanios).

Comment: Congrats.. What did you do?

Comment: Created instance for navigationitem

Comment: Right.. All the best :)