# How to add UIImageView to navigation bar in swift?

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uiimageview

I have this code that adds a rounded border around a UIImage using UIImageView and I've used UITapGestureRecognizer to let the user tap on the button:

```
var profilePicture = UIImageView()
func setupUserProfileButton() {

    let defaultPicture = UIImage(named: "profilePictureSmall")
    profilePicture = UIImageView(image: defaultPicture)
    profilePicture.layer.cornerRadius = profilePicture.frame.width / 2
    profilePicture.clipsToBounds = true
    profilePicture.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    profilePicture.layer.borderWidth = 1

    // Letting users click on the image
    profilePicture.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(profilePictureTapped))
    profilePicture.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

}
```

How can I add this to the left side of a navigation bar? Is it possible? And I don't think the tap gesture is needed if I can add the ImageView to the navigation bar as a barButtonItem, so you can ignore that. I kinda found some similar questions but they were in objective C and none of what I tried worked.

Here is what I came up with based on an answer:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class CreateStoryPage: BaseAndExtensions {

    let userProfileButton = UIButton(type: .custom)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Call all the elements
        setupUserProfileButton()

    }
    // MARK:- Setups
    // Setup the user profile button
    func setupUserProfileButton() {

        userProfileButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "profilePictureSmall.png"), for: .normal)
        userProfileButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30)
        userProfileButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(profilePictureTapped), for: .touchUpInside)

        let userProfileView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30))
        userProfileView.layer.cornerRadius = 14
        userProfileView.backgroundColor = .red

        userProfileView.addSubview(userProfileButton)

        let leftNavBarItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: userProfileView)
        self.navigationItem.setLeftBarButton(leftNavBarItem, animated: true)


    }

    // if user taps on profile picture
    @objc func profilePictureTapped() {

        let userProfilePage = UserProfilePage()
        present(userProfilePage, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UIBarButtonItem with rounded corners and shadow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23886528/uibarbuttonitem-with-rounded-corners-and-shadow)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    let navBtn = UIButton(type: .custom)
    navBtn.setImage("yourImage", for: .normal)
    navBtn.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 28, height: 28)
    navBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.openProfile(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

    let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 28, height: 28))
    view.cornerRadius = 14
    view.backgroundColor = Global.colorBlue

    view.addSubview(navBtn)

    let leftNavBarItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: view)
    self.navigationItem.setLeftBarButton(leftNavBarItem, animated: true)


    @objc
    func openProfile(_ sender: UIButton) {

    }
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195309/discussion-on-answer-by-awais-khan-how-to-add-uiimageview-to-navigation-bar-in-s).

Answer (score 1):

Try this;

```
private func setupRightItem() {
    let userProfileButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
    userProfileButton.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    userProfileButton.clipsToBounds = true
    userProfileButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(profilePictureTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    userProfileButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "profilePictureSmall.png"), for: .normal)
    userProfileButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30)

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: userProfileButton)

    userProfileButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
    userProfileButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
  }

  @objc private func goProfile() {
    /// -> Action
  }
```